# UITextField doesn't take whole screen width

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I'm using a UITextField and a UIButton as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

Sometimes the "test" button needs to be disabled so I disable it with this code:

```
    [_hButton setEnabled:NO];
    [_hButton setHidden: true];
```

But the problem is that the UITextField doesn't take the whole width from the screen like you can see here:

[image]

This are the settings from the UITextField in my storyboard:

[image]

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you doing this `[_hButton setEnabled:NO];
    [_hButton setHidden: true];`, you have to modify textField width.

Your code should be..

```
CGRect oldFrame = yourTextField.frame;
CGRect frameNew = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x,oldFrame.origin.y,oldFrame.size.width + _hbutton.frame.size.width,oldFrame.size.height);
yourTexField.frame = frameNew;
```

When you want back this, just do reverse calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Although the button isHidden, it is still there. You should remove it from the view completely for the desired effect `[_hButton removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: If _hButton want to enable again means, Is `addSubview` enough? it will working?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but i think it will. Also i forgot to say that he would still need to do manual frame setup on textField, so i think your answer is better :)

Comment: Ok ok If your answer will work well ,this is the good way. That's y I asked.. :)

Answer (score 0):

UITextView is not resizing since the button is still there, it's just not visible. After you hide the button, adjust UItextView frame manually.